# Ordenar Lista de Componentes Angular

Tags: angular, front-end, angular-material

Fala Galera!
Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

- imaginem uma DIV que dentro dela existam vários componentes como o exemplo abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
      <app-fogao></app-fogao>
    
        <app-geladeira></app-geladeira>
    
        <app-notebook></app-notebook>
    
        <app-ar-condicionado></app-ar-condicionado>
    
        <app-televisao></app-televisao>
    
        <app-celular></app-celular>
    
        <app-maquina-lavar></app-maquina-lavar>
    
    </div>
```

E ai eu queira ordenar a exibição destes componentes conforme a ordem que eu receber do backend, algo do tipo abaixo:

```
    let ordemProdutos = [
      {produto: 'fogao' , posicao: 3},
      {produto: 'geladeira' , posicao: 5},
      {produto: 'notebook' , posicao: 1},
      {produto: 'ar-condicionado' , posicao: 4},
      {produto: 'televisao' , posicao: 2},
      {produto: 'celular' , posicao: 7},
      {produto: 'maquina-lavar' , posicao: 6}
    ];
```

E então a exibição dos componentes que inicialmente ficariam igual ao trecho 01, fosse alterada para ficar igual o trecho abaixo (conforme a ordem recebida acima):

```
<div class="row">
  <app-notebook></app-notebook>

  <app-televisao></app-televisao>
  
  <app-fogao></app-fogao>
  
  <app-ar-condicionado></app-ar-condicionado>
  
  <app-geladeira></app-geladeira>

  <app-maquina-lavar></app-maquina-lavar>
  
  <app-celular></app-celular>

    </div>
```

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer essa ordenação dos componentes dinamicamente?

OBS.: Esta é uma forma de demonstrar o problema que eu tenho. os componentes reais não possuem estes nomes.
Não pude criar uma componente genérico porque cada um deles são completamente diferentes em termos de conteúdo e estrutura. Eles são exibidos lado a lado e eu preciso criar uma forma de ordená-los de acordo com o posicionamento que cada componente possui gravado no backend.

Answer (score 1):

O melhor seria primeiro ordenar sua lista

```
ordemProdutosOrdenada = ordemProdutos.sort((a,b)=> a.posicao - b.posicao)
```

ai vc pode usar o ngComponentOutlet dentro de um ngfor pra instaciar seus componentes dinamicamente

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="produto.produto"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Consegui fazer exatamente o seu exemplo.
Vou me aprofundar ainda mais neste assunto.
Criei um projetinho no GitHub e no StackBlitz 
Caso queira dar uma olhada link abaixo:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkcdsr?file=src/app/app.component.ts
- https://github.com/MatiasNeto/ComponenteDinamico